# Input data undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, undefined

I have table with input in it.

```
<tr id="1">
    <th>1</th>
    <th>ball</th>
    <th>10euro</th>
    <th><input type="text" class="input col-xs-1 sum" value="1"></th>
    <th style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i></th>
    <th style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" id="addproduct1"></i></th>
</tr>
```

And script

```
var data = $("#1.sum").value;
alert(data);
```

But data is always undefined/null. The every way i try is null/undefined. Can you help me and tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is close, but wrong. Without a space between your ID and class, you're looking for an element with an ID of `1` AND a class of `sum` - you want:

```
var data = $("#1 .sum").val();
```

Now it looks for an element with a class of `sum` that is a child of an element with the ID of `1`.

Also, `.value` is a property on a DOM element, you have a jQuery element above, so you want `.val()`

Comment: Thank you,but unfortunately still undefined :(

Comment: may be: $("#1 .sum").val() instead?

Comment: Now working. Thank you so much. Small things like one bad letter are hardest :)

Comment: @gaetanoM - Nice catch, edited the answer to reflect.